# Animating page navigation in WP 8.1 while the current page stays still

Tags: animation, windows-phone-8, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

In WP 8.1 Store app, how can I change page animation upon navigating to another page within the frame such that the current page stays still while the new page is animating on top of it by moving from the top of the screen to the bottom?

I'm currently animating my navigation like so:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     Frame.ContentTransitions = new TransitionCollection
     {
            new PaneThemeTransition{Edge = EdgeTransitionLocation.Top}
     };
}
```

But this is animating both pages by moving the current one from bottom to top while the second one simultaneously moves from top to bottom. I'm also seeing a black background while the pages are moving for screen area that's not occupied by any content.

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately can not navigate to a different page and keep the previous page visible during the animation. That is why all page Transitions right now only support an In-Transition and an Out-Transition. We discussed the issue with Microsoft developers during this years //Build so I'm certain of this information.

If you really need that effect you can perhaps achieve it using a workaround. Instead of placing your content on separate pages you would create user controls and animate those while staying on a single page. This however can be a little tricky due to you manually having to manage "navigation" between the user controls instead of having the system deal with it for regular pages.

More information on how to implement animations in Windows Phone Silverlight Apps can be found in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago and it is kind of a workaround as well but it might do the trick for you.

You can place a Frame object taking all the available space on your current page. Then, instead of navigating from your current Page Frame, you navigate from the Frame object you put on top of your actual page.

The problem with this approach is that you would really "get rid" of the first page.
But this can work for you, or at least give you another insight of the problem.